# ReactJS - Like and Unlike using same button - updating without refreshing page

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a Udemy course and they have an unlike and like button where they're separate from each other. I want to try to make them into 1 button, so buttons would toggle and update the number of likes without refreshing the page.

I have something like this in the return() within a functional component

```
{posts.filter(item => item.user.toString() === user).length > 0 ? (
  <button onClick={e => unlike(_id)}>Unlike</button>
) : (
  <button onClick={e => like(_id)}>Like</button>
)}
```

This ony renders once page loads, and it will only render either Unlike or Like depending on the conditional statement. User can only like once, so if user already liked a post, on page load, it will load Unlike button, if user clicks Unlike, it will stay Unlike, and not refresh the view.

I'd like to update this also:

```
{posts.length}
```

How would I go about doing this without refreshing the page and that it'll rerender on user's action?

---

**actions/post.js**

```
// Like
export const like = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/like/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: { id, likes: res.data }
    });
  } catch (err) {

  }
};

// Unlike
export const unlike = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/unlike/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: { id, likes: res.data }
    });
  } catch (err) {

  }
};
```

---

**reducers/post.js**

```
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  POST_ERROR,
  UPDATE_LIKES,
  ADD_POST
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  post: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, payload],
        loading: false
      };
    case POST_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case UPDATE_LIKES:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id
            ? { ...post, likes: payload.likes }
            : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your unlike() and like() function. You can perform the action without page refresh using AJAX, but need to know currently how you perform your like/unlike first

Comment: @jimmy5312 updated with like and unlike

Comment: post your reducer code as well, this doesn't tell us anything about the logic you have implemented

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier updated with reducers! thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

in the unlike method the action type is "**UPDATE_LIKE**" while the  reducer expects "**UPDATE_LIKES**"

Also you are updating **likes** property in your reducer but for rendering you are checking the **user** property for conditional rendering

```
/*
  you are updating the likes property in your reducer so react will only change the UI if you check the posts.likes instead of posts.user
*/
{posts.filter(item => item.user.toString() === user).length > 0 ? ( 
  <button onClick={e => unlike(_id)}>Unlike</button>
) : (
  <button onClick={e => like(_id)}>Like</button>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks, updated, but still wasn't working for me. I'm still new to all this reactjs stuff, can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

so I am doing the same course and wanted to do the same thing that you wish to do and saw this question, here's what I did and it worked for me. I tried making the like button like Instagram, where the heart gets filled with red if liked.

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD77y.jpg)

I sent a boolean prop "liked" which helped to know if the post has been liked by the user logged in:

**Posts.js**

```
        <div className="posts">
         {posts.map((post) => (
           <PostItem
             key={post._id}
             post={post}
             liked={
               post.likes.filter((like) => like.user === user._id).length > 0
                 ? true
                 : false
             }
           />
         ))}
       </div>
```

**PostItem.js**

Used Hooks here for the state of the button.

```
        const [like, setLike] = useState(liked);

        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={async (e) => {
            like ? await removeLike(_id) : await addLike(_id);
            setLike(!like);
          }}
          className="btn btn-light"
        >
          {like ? (
            <i className="fas fa-heart like-color"></i>
          ) : (
            <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
          )}{" "}
          <span>{likes.length}</span>
        </button>
```